# Sending SMS and getting SMS gateway domain from a given number using PHP

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

I am trying to send SMS  using the code

```
var_dump(mail("9xxxxxxxxx@ideacellular.net", "", "Your packaged has arrived!", "From: My Name>\r\n"));
```

referred from this [link](https://davidwalsh.name/send-text-message) and this code is returning :

```
bool(true)
```

But  I'm not getting any SMS in my mobile phone. Anyone knows why this function is not working? I saw the same code in some other links also.

Can anyone help me to find what I'm doing wrong? Also I need to get the SMS gateway domain (Eg: ideacellular.net) , given a number.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Sms provider is supposed to give you an API and ways of manipulating it. Sending sms using the mail function is  somewhat lemme say not good

Comment: which country are you trying to send the SMS to? The `ideacellular.net` gateway works in india...

Comment: @Dekel..The mobile number belongs to India only..

Comment: Since it's not a paid-service it might not work anymore...

Comment: You can check this list: http://gleez.com/articles/sms/email-to-mobile-send-sms-freely-india/ it might help you (although its really old one...)

Comment: @Jenz email to sms is old technique and deprecated now. There are only paid sms services available in india Ex. https://www.springedge.com you can get Restapi and call api in code using CURL